# MonoDevolop/Xamarin Windows.forms Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop And Xamarin. Then I tested the mono-devolop by running the application they said to run to test the install and it worked. Then I tried it in Xamarin but it said "The Tyoe or namespace name 'Form' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?" What should I do?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
public class HelloWorld : Form
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Application.Run (new HelloWorld ());
        OperatingSystem.Equals ("mac");
    }

    public HelloWorld ()
    {
        Text = "Hello Mono World";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the references by right clicking the reference folder clicking "edit references" then select all mono-devolop ones